# Sorting by aggregate of two fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo database with documents that look like this:

```
{
    PublishedDate: [date],
    PublishedDateOverride: [NullableDate],
    ...
}
```

The reason I have the override as a separate field is that it is important to know the original published date as well as the overridden one.

When I get these documents back I want to sort them by their "apparent" published date. That is if there is an override it should use that, otherwise use the original.

Our current system just sorts by `PublishedDateOverride` and then by `PublishedDate` which of course groups all of those with a `null` override together.

For a concrete example take the following four documents:

```
A = {
    PublishedDate: 2014-03-14,
    PublishedDateOverride: 2014-03-24,
    ...
}

B = {
    PublishedDate: 2014-01-21,
    PublishedDateOverride: 2014-02-02,
    ...
}

C = {
    PublishedDate: 2014-03-01,
    PublishedDateOverride: null,
    ...
}

D = {
    PublishedDate: 2014-03-27,
    PublishedDateOverride: null,
    ...
}
```

The desired sort order would be D (2014-03-27), A (2014-03-14), C (2014-03-01), B (2014-02-02).

I need to be able to do this in the database since I am also paging this data so I can't just sort after getting it out of the database.

So the question:

What is the best way to achieve this goal? Is there a way to sort by an expression? Is there a way to have a calculated field such that whenever I update a document it will put the appropriate date in there to sort on?

I'm doing this in C# in case that is relevant but I would assume any solution would be a mongo one, not in my client code.

Comment: Per your stated desires, shouldn't B be pulled back with 2014-02-02 as the published date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a projection of only the valid and greater date then use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with the [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator and the [`$gt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) operator. A basic shell example for translation (which is not hard) :

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "date": { "$cond": [
            { "$gt": [
                "$PublishedDate",
                "$PublishedDateOverride"
             ]},
             "$PublishedDate",
             "$PublishedDateOverride"
        ]}
    }},
    { "$sort": { "date": 1 } }
])
```

So that basically breaks down your documents to having the "date" field set to which ever of those two fields had the greater value. Then you can sort on the result. All processed server side.

Comment: I've established that $cond is great and that's bought to my attention the `$ifnull` operator which seems even better. Sadly I am having trouble working out how to translate to the c# drivers. Is that something you can assist with? I've found suggestions of basically creating the BSON query documents like the above but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it...

Comment: @Chris depends on your case, but yes the first part of `$cond` (essentially a ternary) takes a "logical" operation. So whatever suits best. Busy with some things now, but if this is still stumping you I'll try to come back to try and give an example to the BSON generation. Soldier on though. Aggregate well suit you better over large sets than client side processing of this sort.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I'll accept this as the answer since it does what I want. If I have trouble with translating still later I'll open a new question (though may ping you here if I do).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
datesCollection.OrderBy(d => d.PublishedDateOverride!= null? d.PublishedDateOverride: d.PublishedDate)
```

Comment: Can the query provider actually translate that query though?

Comment: I've no idea. The question is tagged with C# tag - if it cannot use that kind of linq extension, then it's not a C# related problem. He can do that for sure if the sorting will be performed locally.

Comment: It is C#, that's not the issue, the issue is that `IQueryable` objects, by design, take a LINQ query written in C# and translate it into "something else".  In most cases there are things that can be done with LINQ that various query providers can't do.  This may or may not be one of them.

Comment: I tagged it with C# because the details of the mongo driver might be relevant as Servy says. I'll try this anyway to find out if the provider can translate it. If it can I'll feel really stupid. ;-)

Comment: NotSupportedExceptions sadly though perhaps not surprisingly. :(

Comment: Too bad. You can still do it locally if it's not too complicated query - just use `ToList()` extension, and then sort it, although it's may not be desired.

Comment: As I said in my original question locally is not an option since I am getting results in batches so in order to be able to say "first 10" it has to be able to sort it on the server. I've got a backup plan involving storing the data differently (eg an extra "PublishedDateSortValue" field that gets updated on each write) but that is not that easier to implement and comes with a different set of problems. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)

> To sort on multiple fields, create a compound index.

Comment: That looks like its all about sorting by fields consecutively. ie sort by A and then B which is explicitly what I don't want to do. I want to choose whether A or B is the value used for the sort based on whether B is null or not. If you think I am misreading then can you put in some code explaining how to do this.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't comprehend your initial problem properly.